# Realizar pago por mercado pago

Tags: javascript, html, web

estoy intentando meterme en el mundo de las paginas web, aprendiendo de a poco HTML, CSS y JavaScript, tengo creada una pagina muy básica, la cual tiene una sección de "login" en la que puedes registrarte con tu email. luego en otra sección tiene 2 artículos a la venta, solo 2, por lo que necesito que el usuario al dar click allí lo redireccione a una pagina en donde pueda realizar su pago a través de mercado pago, pero yo de alguna manera tengo que saber quien es el usuario que compro ese articulo y a su vez enviarle un mensaje automáticamente al correo con el que se registro... como dije soy muy nuevo en todo esto, no tengo ni idea por donde empezar por eso no adjunto código de mi sitio. espero puedan ayudarme y comprendan mi problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si estás empezando te recomendaría que empieces con la integración más simple que ofrece mercado pago en cobros online, el checkout pro, lo más simple es seguir al pie de la letra la documentación que ofrece mercado pago, aquí te dejo el link:

[Mercado Pago Checkout Pro](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/introduction)

Te agrego como se inicia el proceso de acuerdo a la documentación:

¿Qué es el Checkout Pro?
Checkout Pro es la integración que te permite cobrar a través de nuestro formulario web desde cualquier dispositivo de manera simple, rápida y segura.

Checkout Pro ofrece:
Pagar con los principales medios de pago del país.

Una experiencia de compra adaptada y accesible desde cualquier celular o computadora.

Compras en un click. Al pagar con una cuenta de Mercado Pago, se recuerdan los datos y tarjetas de los compradores, por lo que permite pagos ingresando solo el código de seguridad o dinero en cuenta.

Compras de invitados. No es necesario crear una cuenta de Mercado Pago para poder hacer el pago.

Pago con dos tarjetas. Por ejemplo, para casos de montos altos.

La dificultad de integración es baja.

Glosario
Sabemos que algunos términos son nuevos. Antes de empezar, te los dejamos a mano.

Preferencia (preference)    Es la información del producto o servicio que se quiere ofrecer. Entre los atributos más importantes de una preferencia se definen: la descripción, el monto y los items. Al generarla se obtiene la URL para iniciar el flujo de pago.

Credenciales (credentials)  Tus credenciales son las claves que te proporcionamos para que puedas configurar tus integraciones.

Public key. Clave pública de la aplicación para conocer, por ejemplo, los medios de pago y cifrar datos de tarjeta. Debes usarla solo para tus integraciones.
Access token. Clave privada de la aplicación para generar pagos. Debes usarla solo para tus integraciones.

Para poder encontrarlas, ve a tus credenciales y selecciona las productivas.

Punto de inicio (init_point)    Es la URL que se obtiene al momento de generar la preferencia y que da inicio al flujo de pago del Checkout Pro.

Ítem (ítem) Hace referencia al producto o servicio que se quiere ofrecer. Puede ser uno o una lista.

Aplicación (application)    Las aplicaciones sirven para procesar los pagos del vendedor. Cada aplicación identifica a una integración en particular, ya que cada una tiene sus credenciales propias. Una cuenta de Mercado Pago puede tener múltiples aplicaciones.

Puedes encontrar la información de cada una en credenciales. Al ingresar, se creará una automáticamente o puedes crear una aplicación cada vez que lo necesites.

Requisitos previos
Para continuar, verifica los requisitos previos necesarios:

1. Acceso a cuenta de Mercado Pago o Mercado Libre
   Para poder comenzar la integración, es necesario contar con una cuenta de Mercado Pago o Mercado Libre. Si aún no tienes una, puedes crear una cuenta de Mercado Pago cuando quieras.
2. Instalación de SDK de Mercado Pago
   Instala el SDK oficial para simplificar tu interacción con nuestras APIs.

Trabajando con php, instala Composer para usar el SDK. Luego ejecuta el siguiente código en la línea de comandos:

```
php composer.phar require "mercadopago/dx-php"
```

Usa los ejemplos descargables para conocer la integración completa o para adaptarlos según lo que necesites.

[Ejemplos Descargables](https://github.com/mercadopago/checkout-payment-sample)

1. ¿Cómo me integro?
   Genera tu preferencia

1.1 Suma la SDK descargada de Mercado Pago en tu proyecto.

1.2 Agrega las credenciales para habilitar el uso de la SDK de Mercado Pago.

1.3 Configura la preferencia según tu producto o servicio.

2. Suma el checkout a tu sitio

Pasos para integrarte
Instalar el Checkout Pro consta de dos pasos:

1. Genera tu preferencia

1.1 Suma la SDK de Mercado Pago en tu proyecto:

```
<?php
// SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

1.2 Agrega las credenciales para habilitar el uso de la SDK de Mercado Pago:

```
<?php
// SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN');
?>
```

1.3 Configura la preferencia según tu producto o servicio:

```
<?php
// SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN');

// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = 'Mi producto';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = 75.56;
$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->save();
?>
```

2. Suma el checkout a tu sitio
   Por último, suma el siguiente código para mostrar el botón de pago de tu Checkout Pro en el lugar que quieras que aparezca.

   id; ?>">

Importante
No te olvides de acceder desde otro navegador o cerrar la sesión de tu cuenta de Mercado Pago antes de probarlo. No puedes pagar con la misma cuenta que creaste el formulario de pago.

¡Excelente! Terminaste tu integración.
Haz clic en el link dentro de tu sitio y prueba la integración de tu Checkout Pro.

Próximos pasos: probar la integración.

[Prueba tu integración](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/test-integration)

Comment: https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-api/receiving-payment-by-card

Comment: Checkout Api es más compleja de implementar.

Comment: Muy injusto el comentario, he tratado de orientarlo, incluir parte de la respuesta sería para confusión porque la documentación es dificil de mejorar por este medio, encima me quitan puntos por orientarlo a donde está la mejor información sobre lo que consulta.

Comment: Saludos @FabianM, te recomiendo leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) sobre todo las secciones **Ofrece contexto para los enlaces** y **Contesta preguntas bien formadas**, tu respuesta podría ser correcta *pero* también podría estar mas completa, imagino que si la mejoras el usuario que votó negativo también lo quitara. ;)

Comment: Dale, ampliado, saludos.